# Can't catch error thrown from Node's built-in function callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been studying a lot on asynchronous javascript, from callbacks to promises to async/await.

Now I'm having a hard time understanding why do I lose control over error handling in the following code sample. I've even dived into Node's source code, but that gave me more trouble than answers.

This is what I do:

1. Inside a global try/catch block, I call Node's built-in **fs.readFile**, giving it a *callback that just throws an error*;
2. The error isn't caught, however, and I suppose it somehow bubbles up to the global scope, provoking the JS Engine to emit an *uncaughtException* event.

> ```
> const { readFile } = require('node:fs')
>
> process.on('uncaughtExceptionMonitor', (error, origin) => {
>   console.log('\nuncaughtExceptionMonitor handler: {')
>   console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`)
>   console.log(`ORIGIN: ${origin}`)
>   console.log('}\n')
> })
>
> try {
>   readFile('./jsconfig.json', 'utf8', (err, res) => {
>     if (err) console.log('failed to read file')
>     if (res) console.log('successfully read file')
>
>     throw new Error(`THROWN BY BUILT-IN FUNCTION'S CALLBACK`) //error thrown
>   })
> } catch (error) {
>   console.log(`error caught by readFile's outer scope`) // not caught here
> }
> ```

When run, it gives me the following result:

> successfully read file
>
> uncaughtExceptionMonitor handler: { ERROR: Error: THROWN BY BUILT-IN
> FUNCTION'S CALLBACK ORIGIN: uncaughtException }
>
> C:\Users\Heavy\Documents\dev\hwoarang\leg.js:15
> throw new Error(`THROWN BY BUILT-IN FUNCTION'S CALLBACK`) //error thrown
> ^
>
> Error: THROWN BY BUILT-IN FUNCTION'S CALLBACK
> at C:\Users\Heavy\Documents\dev\hwoarang\leg.js:15:11
> at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)

This is my first question so I'm not quite comfortable with Stackoverflow's formatting. I apologize for that.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`try...catch` applies to the code that runs synchronously in the `try` block. The callback given to the `readFile` function, does not execute synchronously, but *after* the `try` block has completed execution (and all synchronous code that follows it until the call stack has been emptied and the job queue(s) are processed by the engine). Once execution *completes* the `try` block, it can never happen to still get in the `catch` block later.

Later, a new execution context is created where the callback is executed. This execution context knows nothing about this `try..catch` block.

You can make use of the promise version of `fs`:

```
const { promises: { readFile } } = require("fs");

async function test() {
    try {
        const res = await readFile('./jsconfig.json', 'utf8');
        console.log('successfully read file');
        throw new Error(`THROWN AFTER AWAIT`) //error thrown
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`error caught`) // will be  caught
    }
}

test();
```

Here, with `await`, the `try` block is suspended together with the function's execution context. Once the awaited promise is resolved, that function context is restored with its unfinished `try` block, and then execution continues within that block, so that an error will be caught and make the `catch` block execute.

Comment: Brilliant!

Your answer has exactly what I was looking for: some reasoning involving the event loop/callback queue/execution contexts...

These subjects were already on my study pipeline. Your answer motivated a bit more to research them.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

`readFile` is an asynchronous operation; so, it won't execute in the typical step-by-step (line-by-line) way. So, when the error is thrown, the synchronous code that you have will have been executed already.

Simplest solution here is to use synchronous [readFileSync](https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs) that will run within the same execution context.

If you want to have the synchronous looking code while still executing an asynchronous code, you can promisify the `readFile` function and call that using async/await:

```js
const readFilePromise (filename, format) = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  readFile(filename, format, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(res);
    }
  });
});

// usage
(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await readFilePromise('./jsconfig.json', 'utf8');
    console.log('successfully read the file', res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('failed to read file');
  }
})();
```

Comment: So, in my code, *readFile*'s callback will run way after the try block finishes executing. I'm certain I had had that understanding in a similar situation before but I guess it hadn't matured.

Thank you!